# Visual Studio Code terminal not working properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, integer

The terminal won't output what I programmed. Before, I have written `num = float(input("enter num"))`, and it would output a float. But after I changed it to an int, the terminal would still output floats. And this happened with other things as well. Does anyone have any solution to this?

I was expecting the terminal to be able to recognize the change I applied to my code, but it didn't, and I have to relaunch VS Code each time for it to work with the code I have written.

Comment: If the answer by dosia96 doesn't solve your problem, you need to provide more info.

Comment: Have you saved your file? How do you run files and how does it perform using the `run selection line in interactive window`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your code is saved. I don't know how you run your code. If you're typing in a command in your terminal to run your code like (node test.js), you can Ctrl+c to stop it and re-run your code.

At the very least, you don't need to relaunch your VS Code, you can just close your terminal, and add a new one.
[image]

Comment: good guess, but I'm a little doubtful because the asker said "_I have to relaunch VS Code each time for it to work with the code I have written._" and I'm not aware of VS Code saving files on its own closure- although it does remember unsaved changes.

Comment: hahaha, need more information...